# Datagridview needs to hide Scrollbar, but scroll should be achievable through code

Tags: c#, datagridview, scroll

I have 2 Datagrids with same number of columns

`Datagrid1` is displaying only headers,
`Datagrid2` is just below it displaying all the data.
In essence, the 2 grid's need to be synchronised to appear as 1 grid.

My issue here is I need to hide the horizontal scrollbar of `datagrid1`, but display only that for the `datagrid2`.
When the user scroll's the `datagrid2`, I need to programmatically synchronise the headers on `datagrid1`.

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 6):

Try this..

```
dataGridViews1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;

 private void dataGridViews2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
       int offSetValue = dataGridViews1.HorizontalScrollingOffset;

      try 
          { 
            dataGridViews1.HorizontalScrollingOffset = offSetValue; 
          }
      catch { }

           dataGridViews1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the DataGridViews ScrollBasr property to hide vertical scrollbar

e.g.

```
dataGridViews1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
```

or see other enumeration value at link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbars

Comment: Thanks Hatsoft, I understand how to hide the scrollbar... How do I synchronize it when the user scrolls the second grid ?

Comment: @Kamath do you mean if user moves scrollbar of 2nd grid the even 1st grids scrollbar must move?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the VerticalScrollingOffset value to position the Scrolling bar at the index you want. Handle the Scroll event in the second DGV and set this VerticalScrollingOffset for the first DGv. This should help.

Answer (score 0):

I have same concept like you..I have solved it as per folowing : may it help u.

```
private void dgvHeader_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        //When Header Grid Width Changes automatically Below Grid's COLUMN width will be changes
        dgvData.Columns[e.Column.Index].Width = e.Column.Width;
    }
```