# Can we make a datagridview scrollable but have the scrollbar invisible, using windows form .net in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am looking to make the scrollbar of a dataviewgrid invisible but I still want to keep the functionality of scrolling. This is done on .net windows form platform.

Comment: How will you scroll it without the scroll bar?  The mouse wheel?  Will that be clear to the user?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529228/datagridview-needs-to-hide-scrollbar-but-scroll-should-be-achievable-through-co

Comment: thx, its very similar to that post, basically I am scrolling using touch screen and i am looking to make the scrollbar insivible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally I wasn't able to make it invisible therefore I just used a workaround where I add a panel over the scrollbar to hide it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
dataGridViews1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
```

Comment: this removes the functionality of scrolling

Comment: wow, it looks like that the OP wants it invisible but still wants it to support the scrollability. Hence this answer seems not to be what the OP wants :>